# NSTextView scroll point changing when edits applied

Tags: ios, swift, xamarin

I have an `NSTextView` that users can type into. What's different is that I often make changes to the `TextStorage` *while* the user is typing in it (i.e. some information comes in over the network, and I need to represent that into the `NSTextView` by merging in these changes).

I can do that successfully - I've created a `MovableCursor` which keeps track of `SelectedRange` even when changes are happening behind the scenes.

I have this code working on `iOS (UITextView)` and the `Mac (NSTextView)`. The problem is, on the Mac, the `NSTextView` usually jumps in the Scroller (i.e. the visible position in the View changes). It does not move at all on the `UITextView` - everything works perfectly, the cursor doesn't move in the window even though changes have happened to the `TextStorage`.

Simply using `ScrollRangeToVisible` doesn't work - it may make the Selection visible, but it necessarily make it visible in the same place.

I've tried grabbing the Scroller's VerticalScroller position, and then reapply it after making changes.

```
var scroll_pos = contentViewScroller.VerticalScroller.FloatValue;
...make changes...
contentViewScroller.VerticalScroller.FloatValue = scroll_pos;
```

Well, I can see the scrollbar doesn't move (expected), but the text still does. Somehow the scroller gets out of alignment with its position through the `NSTextView`. When I start moving the scrollbar, it seems to "flick" a little and get back in alignment.

So... Any thoughts on how I can make changes to an NSTextView's TextStorage, while keeping the Cursor (or SelectedRange) fixed in the same position on the screen.

[Note: of course there are times when this immobility is not possible - for example if everything before the cursor was erased, then the cursor must move to the top. That's ok.]

Many thanks.

Comment: The jumps happened when you change the `TextStorage`?

Comment: Correct. When I make changes to the TextStorage, the text scrolls up or down, so the cursor position changes on the screen (but not in the NSTextView). Its jarring for people editing at the time.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? I'm struggling with a similar problem.

Comment: I have not. :-(. My current plan is to experiment with making very small changes at a time... but that will wait for time in the next sprint.